# Sorting algorithm for a table

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting

I need a sorting algorithm made into a function to help with this table.

The code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/L2amkyL6/1/

I need to get the b1, b2, b3, and b4 order. However, every time I tried to sort, I can't seem to get passed the "b". Like if I write b10, then that would appear first too since it only counts the b1 in b10. And b9 would appear last, even though there is a b10.

Anyways: I wrote a similar code to a similar table here: http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3t4/540/

```
function sortData(){
  var tableData = document.getElementById('data_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0);
  var rowData = tableData.getElementsByTagName('tr');            
  for(var i = 0; i < rowData.length - 1; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rowData.length - (i + 1); j++){

      var txt = parseInt(rowData.item(j).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML);
      var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
      numb = numb.join("");

      var txt2 = parseInt(rowData.item(j+1).getElementsByTagName('td').item(0).innerHTML);
      var numb2 = txt2.match(/\d/g);
      numb2 = numb2.join("");
      if(numb > numb2){
        tableData.insertBefore(rowData.item(j+1),rowData.item(j));
      }
    }
  }
}
// Table data sorting ends....
```

That failed miserably.

I need help. Can someone help me create this function. I literally just learned JS in 1 day.

Comment: I need a function for the first one: https://jsfiddle.net/L2amkyL6/1/

Answer (score 0):

The sort function is currently quite brittle, but you should be able to get an idea from this and improve on it.

```js
function sortTable(){
  var parent = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var rows = Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll("tr"));

  rows.sort(function(a,b){
    var aText = a.children[1].innerText.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0];
    var aNumber = parseInt(a.children[1].innerText.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
    var bText = b.children[1].innerText.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0];
    var bNumber = parseInt(b.children[1].innerText.match(/\d+/g)[0]);

    if(aText < bText) return -1;
    if(aText > bText) return 1;
    return aNumber - bNumber;
  });
  
  rows.forEach(function(item) { parent.appendChild(item); });
}

document.getElementById("short_data").addEventListener("click", sortTable);
```

```css
table { margin-bottom: 1em; }
table tr td:first-child { width: 25%; }
```

```html
<table id="data_table" width="200" border="1">
  <tr><td>Last</td><td>b10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>01</td><td>b6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>04</td><td>b3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>06</td><td>b1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>02</td><td>b5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>a1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>a10</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="short_data">short_data</button>
```

Comment: you are amazing and I had 15 more reputation points, I would like you

Comment: what if I only have 1 column instead of the two columns?

Comment: btw this isn't homework or anything like that. this is more of a project. I was stuck all yesterday and today.

Comment: one column (or the first) would be **.children[0]**